# How to bind one selector depending on another selector in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, selector

I have an input form with 2 selector fields - country and city. And the city-list has to upload only cities from the current country. After choosing the country I have it in the state. But I have a problem with to filter cities list. When I write like filter(key => key["country"] === 1 ), where 1 is ID of the country, it workes. How do I can use there current state of the country, if comparison key["country"] === this.state.country doesn't work?

```
...
onChange = event => {
   this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  getOptionItems = (Items) => Items.map(item =>
    <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
      {item.name}
    </option>
  )

<div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              id="country"
              value={this.state.country}
              name="country"
              onChange={this.onChange}
            >
              {this.getOptionItems(countries)}
            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              id="city"
              value={this.state.city}
              name="city"
              onChange={this.onChange}
            >
            {Object.values(cities).filter(key => key["country"] === **what condition to write here?**).map(city =>
              <option key={city.id} value={city.id}>
              {city.name}
              </option>
            )}
```

Comment: Show us `this.state.country` and `cities` array

Comment: what error do you get with ```key["country"] === this.state.country```

Comment: it shows empty field. nothing to choose at all

Comment: this.state = {
  ...
      country: "1",
      city: "1",
     ....    
}
  }

Cities are in such file:
 "1": { country: 1, name: "Kyiv" },
  "2": { country: 1, name: "Lviv" },
  "3": { country: 1, name: "Odessa" },
  "4": { country: 1, name: "Dnipro" },
  "5": { country: 1, name: "Kharkiv" },

  "6": { country: 2, name: "Berlin" },
  "7": { country: 2, name: "Dortmund" },
  "8": { country: 2, name: "Drezden" },
  "9": { country: 2, name: "Hamburg" },
  "10": { country: 2, name: "Koln" },.....

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to place **parseInt** in the condition, because this.state.country was saved as '1', '2', '3'. Here was the problem.